# Responsive grid with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have been at this problem for hours.

I am looking to make my website responsive, I have started with mobile first and am working on creating it for the desktop.

My issue:

when I edit the .col for tablet or desktop, the columns will respond but they will not be on the same row.

When the breakpoint hits for the desktop I would like my picture to be to the right of the menu, and the content to be to the right of the picture.

if I make my

```
#menu{float:left} //under CSS desktop breakpoint
```

then i will get my desired result but the menu will lose it's column width.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrtpjhh7/

any advice? I feel as if I am on the right track but something is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired outcome you need to:

1. Wrap whatever you want displayed near the menu inside a `col-9` wrapper.
2. Add `float:left` to your `[class^="col-"]`.

Here's your [fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrtpjhh7/3/).

Comment: this isn't bootstrap, I've just followed http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp
It is just CSS and HTML

Comment: Sorry, there are quite a few similarities between your example and Bootstrap. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem